# How to use MySQL like with order by exact match first

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL 5.5 so that's why I can't use FULLTEXT search so please don't suggest it.

What I wanted to do is if user I have 5 records for example :

```
Amitesh
Ami
Amit
Abhi
Arun
```

and if someone searches for Ami then it should returns Ami first as exact match then Amit & Amitesh

Comment: Select * from Person where name like 'Ami%'

Comment: what if someone search for 'mi' only in that case it should also return 3 records without any order

Comment: What about MySQL 5.5 doesn't allow FULLTEXT search?  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from table t
where col like '%Ami%'
order by (col = 'Ami') desc, length(col);
```

Comment: can you please explain what length(col) is used in query ?

Comment: Probably to return 'Amit' before 'Amitech'

Comment: If I want to match 2 column then how can I write length(col) ?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE col LIKE '%Ami%'
ORDER BY INSTR(col,'Ami') asc, col asc;
```

Comment: Should be a _DESC_ on the first **Order By** to make it work as OP wanted: `ORDER BY INSTR(col, 'Ami') DESC, col ASC`. That said, thanks! This works as a charm in Doctrine/Symfony (with Doctrine extensions enabled) while the selected answer breaks because of the `=` sign

Answer (score 1):

More accurate output can be found using `like` in `order by`.

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE col LIKE '%ami%' order by (col LIKE 'ami%') desc;
```