# How do I do an exact match first with Specification JPA

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm trying to bump an exact query first using Specification and Pageable from spring data.

When making a request to this endpoint `http://localhost:8080/configs?search=PATH`

This is the response now:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "groupId": "PATHOD",
            "type": "company",
        },
        {
            "groupId": "PATH",
            "type": "company",
        },
        {
            "groupId": "APATH",
            "type": "company",
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        ...
    },
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "size": 10,
    "empty": false
}
```

I want to be like, with the exact match bumped to first place:

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "groupId": "APATH",
            "type": "company",
        },
        {
            "groupId": "PATH",
            "type": "company",
        },
        {
            "groupId": "PATHOD",
            "type": "company",
        }
    ],
    "pageable": {
        ....
    },
    "sort": {
        "sorted": true,
        "unsorted": false,
        "empty": false
    },
    "size": 10,
    "empty": false
}
```

This is my code right now, but I don't know how to write the specification

```
fun findAllWithFilters(
        exactMatchFirst: Boolean = false,
        pageable: Pageable
    ): Page<OrderConfig> {
        val spec = and(
            withExactMatchFirst(exactMatchFirst)
        )

        return findAll(spec, pageable)
    }
```

The `PATH` groupId should be the first one to appear in the results

Comment: Isn't this just a sorting problem? If so, have a look at [this baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-sorting).

Comment: No it isn't, I've tried all the sorting directions. I have updated my question with more examples to explain better the problem

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you want sort by relevance?

Comment: I want to bump the exact match to the first item of the array, but since I'm using pageable that needs to happen on the query level. Something like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315669/how-to-use-mysql-like-with-order-by-exact-match-first